# Adding dependencies to existing project via Spring CLI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there any way to add dependencies to existing spring project using Spring CLI **(for instance via shell)**?

I tried to looked for on this website
[docs.spring.io](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-cli.html#cli-default-grab-deduced-coordinates-custom-dependency-management).

But I couldn't find working way of adding dependency like `Spring Web` or `Spring Data JPA` to existing spring project.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `STS` or `Eclipse` for your development then you can easily add `dependencies` using `CLI`.
 You need to press the `Ctrl+Space Bar` in your `pom.xml`.
 It will show you the option with `Edit starters` as shown below, then click on it it will open your `CLI interface`

`Ctrl+Space Bar`
[image: Ctrl+Space Bar]

[image: CLI interface]

Answer (score 1):

You can use pom.xml to add dependencies to your existing spring project whether you created your project by using Spring CLI or any other way.

1. Go to Maven Repository: https://mvnrepository.com/
2. Search for your required dependencies
3. Copy the dependency for maven and paste it in your pom.xml

Comment: Yeah of course you have right and I also know this type of importing dependencies as You said, but was curious if there is a way do this via Spring CLI.

Comment: I checked on few pages, but I couldn't find anywhere mentioned about adding dependencies on existing project via Spring CLI.

Answer (score 1):

To add a dependancy from Spring CLI, you can use the following command:

```
spring init -a <name_of_your_artifact> --dependencies=web,data-jpa <my_project>
```

where:

***<name_of_your_artifact>***: the artifact Id for the project.

and

***<my_project>***: name of the file where the .zip of spring initilizer will be extractred.

Answer (score 0):

To add the dependency in the existing project follow the below steps:

1. Right-click on project
2. Select Spring -> Add Starters
3. Search for the required dependencies and add them
4. Click on Next
5. Select pom.xml/HELP.md or both
6. Finish